# Put an epigraph at the start of the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, epigraphs

I would like to put a quote before all the bibitems in my bibliography, like that:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\epigraph{Awesome quote}{William Shakespeare}
\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Is there a simple way? It seems `thebibliography` waits for `\bibitem` only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could employ the `\bibpreamble` macro of the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) citation and bibliography management package. Note that this approach works both if you use BibTeX to generate the bibliography and if you build the `thebibliography` environment entirely by hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph} % for "\epigraph" macro
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand\bibpreamble{%
  \epigraph{Things should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.}{Albert Einstein}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. \textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) [\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891--921, 1905.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `memoir` class then:

```
\documenclass[...]{memoir}
...
\renewcommand{\prebibhook}{%
  \epigraph{Awesome quote}{William Shakespeare}%
}
...
\begin{thebibliography}{...}
```

and there is no need for the `epigraph` package as it is effectively built into the class.

Answer (score 2):

With the standard settings (no bibliography package added); note that `\bibepigraph` must go before starting the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book} % oneside just for the example
\usepackage{epigraph} % for \epigraph
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \patchcmd

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\list}{\printbibepigraph\list}{}{}
\newcommand{\bibepigraph}[2]{%
  \def\printbibepigraph{\epigraph{#1}{#2}}%
}
\def\printbibepigraph{} % initialize

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\epigraph{%
  F.: What a filthy job!\\
  I.: Could be worse.\\
  F.: How?\\
  I.: Could be raining.
}{Dr.~F.~Frankenstein and Igor}

\lipsum[1-2]


\bibepigraph{If anything can go wrong, it will}{Murphy}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{cantor}
Georg Cantor, \textit{\"Uber eine Eigenschaft des Inbegriffes aller reellen algebraischen Zahlen},
Journal f\"ur die Reine und Angewandte Mathematik \textbf{77} (1874), 258--262.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If BibTeX is used, it will be like

```
\bibepigraph{If anything can go wrong, it will}{Murphy}
\bibliographystyle{<style>}
\bibliography{<filename>}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine the bibliography title and insert the epigraph there. Like this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin = 1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\renewcommand\refname{Reference\epigraph{Awesome quote}{William Shakespeare}}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{einstein} 
Albert Einstein. 
\textit{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. (German) 
[\textit{On the electrodynamics of moving bodies}]. 
Annalen der Physik, 322(10):891–921, 1905.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I got a refname undefined with it